# Combining AVAudioPCMBuffers

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio

I am recording audio with an AVEngine using `installTap(onBus:bufferSize:format)`. This generates AVAudioPCMBuffers that I accumulate. When I'm done recording, I want to concatenate those into a single AVAudioPCMBuffer, so I can use it with other code that operates on buffers. (While in some cases I want to write this to a file, in general I do not.)

Is there a way to combine the buffers without dropping all the way down to the Core Audio layer and manipulating the AudioBufferList?

Comment: I collect and concatenate (into a thread safe ring buffer), and create (file or buffer list(s)), as 2 separate operations.  That allows the same code to safely work in real-time (AU callback(s)), or offline. Unless you have to deal with iPad 1's or iPhone 3gs's, etc., it's safe to assume Floats.

Comment: @hotpaw2 While this part of the code is recording off the microphone (iPhone, iPad or Mac Catalyst), it interacts with audio buffers that are generated by reading WAV files that are generated by other teams using a variety of software (generally Matlab, octave, Audacity, or Audition). Is it safe to assume floats?

Comment: For the non-iOS path, no. WAV file samples are almost always in 16-bit signed integer format.  So you may need to convert formats somewhere to mix them.

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work? (Untested and hard-coded for `Float` data but might be a start)

```
extension AVAudioPCMBuffer {
    func append(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) {
        append(buffer, startingFrame: 0, frameCount: buffer.frameLength)
    }

    func append(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, startingFrame: AVAudioFramePosition, frameCount: AVAudioFrameCount) {
        precondition(format == buffer.format, "Format mismatch")
        precondition(startingFrame + AVAudioFramePosition(frameCount) <= AVAudioFramePosition(buffer.frameLength), "Insufficient audio in buffer")
        precondition(frameLength + frameCount <= frameCapacity, "Insufficient space in buffer")

        let dst = floatChannelData!
        let src = buffer.floatChannelData!

        memcpy(dst.pointee.advanced(by: stride * Int(frameLength)),
               src.pointee.advanced(by: stride * Int(startingFrame)),
               Int(frameCount) * stride * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)

        frameLength += frameCount
    }

    convenience init?(concatenating buffers: AVAudioPCMBuffer...) {
        precondition(buffers.count > 0)
        let totalFrames = buffers.reduce(0, { $1.frameLength })
        self.init(pcmFormat: buffers[0].format, frameCapacity: totalFrames)
        buffers.forEach { append($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that that you have to know before calling `append()` that there is sufficient capacity, and if there isn't, you have to use a different syntax (init). In the common cases, you're not going to know the required capacity. But I certainly see ways to expand this to grow more like how Arrays grow. My current code is not that dissimilar (including the implicit assumption that there is float data, which is not promised, but is really common).